# Save EditText to ArrayList in Android Studio - EDIT 1

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext

I am attempting to take Input Text from a `EditText` field, save the `String` and then add/save it to an `ArrayList` I have in another java `class`. (My `MainActivity` displays all the `facts` I have stored in the `ArrayList`, which works.) Adding new `String` to `ArrayList` from EditText does not work though.

Thanks for the help!

1. **FactBook.java**

   ```
    public class FactBook {
    public ArrayList<String> mFacts = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
            "Quote 1",
            "Quote 2"));

    public String getFact() {

        String fact = "";
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFacts.size());
        fact = mFacts.get(randomNumber);
        return fact;
    }

    public void addFact(String thought) {
        mFacts.add(thought);
    };
   ```
2. InputActivity.java

   ```
    public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mSaveButton;
    private EditText mTextThought;
    private FactBook mFactBook = new FactBook();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    mTextThought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thoughtText);


    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String thought = mTextThought.getText().toString().trim();
            mFactBook.addFact(thought);
            Toast.makeText(InputActivity.this, "Your thought has been added!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mTextThought.setText("");

        }
    };

    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(click);
    } 
    }
   ```

Comment: Ok so what problem you face in this code ?\

Comment: your addFact method is not adding it to list.

Comment: I have fixed the addFact method, but it still does not add to my arraylist!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a problem with your code. Shouldn't the addFact code be this :

```
public void addFact(String thought) {
        mFacts.addFact(thought);
};
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid there. I changed the addFact code, but it still does not add the fact when I run the app and try to use it. Nothing happens. My toast tells me it has been added, EditText is cleared, but no new fact or thought in my arraylist..this is maddening.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addFact(String thought) {
    this.addFact(thought);
```

maybe you should change your code like this:

```
public void addFact(String thought) {
    mFacts.addFact(thought);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `addFact` method should be,

```
 public void addFact(String thought) {
     this.mFacts.add(thought);
 }
```

Comment: It still does not work. . .I did not see this being so tricky.

Comment: Where are you displaying the data in `mFacts`?